# is there a benefit to adding identical CONV2d layers in a row as opposed to continuing to add layers with increased filter size

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

is there a benefit to adding identical layers in a row before like below:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

as opposed to just continuing to increase the filter size like below:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

is it common to add identical layers because its more costly to just continue to increase the number of filters?

i get a higher accuracy when i use identical layers in a row but when i go through examples and books i rarely come across authors adding identical layers and im just curious as to why.

Answer (score 1):

The question is good, yet the answer is dependent on the case.

1. First, it is very important to know the dimension of the images when you apply convolutions. Several papers demonstrate that they do not use a high number of filters in the early layers, since the early layers capture edge/color/shape or similar information https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html. Therefore, using 128 filters instead of 32 in the first layers may not very well increase the overall accuracy.
2. As a consequence of the former observation, the number of filters increases as the neural network becomes deeper, since more task-specific information can be captured. Most of the well-established image classification architectures increase by an exponent of two the number of filters in the convolutional layer.
3. It depends very much on the dataset and that is why a general statement cannot be made, although the former two observations have been both empirically and statistically demonstrated.

   You can start playing with convolutions, add/remove layers, see the improvements(or not) if you add Dropout or BatchNormalization, but I would suggest that you inspect already well-established networks.

   There is no guarantee that architecture X or Y works better. Nowadays the tendency is to use architectures with skip-connections, which ensure the end-to-end gradient flow without loss of information. Try using ResNet50/101(all variants), Xception, DenseNet, SENetwork.